# Notepad++ Log4j Pattern Filter

Tags: regex, filter, log4j, notepad++

I have this log file:

Before

```
<2015-01-22 10:23:51,000> - <DEBUG> - <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> - MyLogClass - Message1
<2015-01-22 10:23:52,000> - <INFO> - <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> - MyLogClass - Message2
<2015-01-22 10:23:53,000> - <ERROR> - <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> - MyLogClass - Message3
```

And I want to delete lines, to obtain this:

After

```
<2015-01-22 10:23:51,000> Thread: '1' - Message1
<2015-01-22 10:23:52,000> Thread: '2' - Message2
<2015-01-22 10:23:53,000> Thread: '2' - Message3
```

Answer (score 2):

Find what:

```
- .*?\[ACTIVE\] Execute(Thread:\s+'[^']*').*(?=\s-)
```

Replace with:

```
\1
```

[DEMO](https://www.regex101.com/r/tI8nV7/5)

Comment: But if the Message contains -, it deletes the first part of the message... I just have to eliminate up to fourth - (the next - to the MyLogClass)

Comment: could you provide an example whiich replicates the above problem?

Comment: You can test the problem if your message is "... - Message1 - Hello". It deletes Message1